# How to add AVVideoDataOutput and AVStillImageOutput on same AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I would like to implement a camera feature where the user can both take still images and record video on the same screen. I have tried adding an AVVideoDataOutput to an AVCaptureSession that already has an AVStillImageOutput, but then I receive this error:

```
Cannot add output <AVCaptureVideoDataOutput: 0x176e6b90> to capture session <AVCaptureSession: 0x176da7c0 [AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]>
<AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x176a62a0 [Back Camera]> -> <AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x176b9bb0>
<AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x176a62a0 [Back Camera]> -> <AVCaptureVideoDataOutput: 0x176ed850> because more than one output of the same type is unsupported'
```

Is there a way to do this in the same viewcontroller with one or multiple AVCaptureSession's?

Comment: By the way why do you need AVStillImageOutput with VideoOutput? both are different things altogether.

Comment: I would like the same viewcontroller to be able to capture still images and videos seamlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve this problem on my own, but I found the framework SwiftyCam that offers the same functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The error implies you are adding two AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to the same session.
AVStillImageOutput is deprecated for ios 10. Have you tried using a AVCapturePhotoOutput instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add `AVStillImageOutput` with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. Use `AVCapturePhotoOutput` instead.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput